# Getting Overflow error when running subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and would like some feedback regarding an overflow error I am encountering when running my code. I have declared all the variables as Double (since I am dealing with large numbers), each Sub represents a different set of equations used to work out the problem I am trying to tackle. These values are then printed in the excel work sheet using the "Range.value" command. The concept of the code is very simple - basically plugging in values from a spreadsheet and calculating an output. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnUx.png)

```
Option Explicit

Dim T, m, d, xb, bh, bd, bm, Th, Tv, phi, L, B, bdr, w, s, a, Pi, h, X1, X2 As Double

Sub Thoriz(T, w, d, Th)
'To calculate the horizontal force on the anchor
Th = T - (w * d)

End Sub

Sub Angle(Th, T, phi, X1)
'To calculate the angle of catenary at connection
X1 = Th / T
phi = Atn(-X1 / Sqr(-X1 * X1 + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1)

End Sub

Sub Tvert(T, phi, s, w, Tv)
'To calculate the total line length
Tv = T * Sin(phi)

s = Tv / w
End Sub

Sub spreadlength1(a, s, d, h, X2)
'To calculate the total spread length
a = ((s ^ 2) - (d ^ 2)) / (2 * d)

X2 = 1 + d / a

h = a * ((Exp(X2) + Exp(–X2)) / 2)

End Sub

Sub spreadlength(B, xb, h)

'Spread length
B = 2 * (xb + h)

End Sub

Sub Caculations()

'INPUTTING OF VALUES
        T = Range("D3").Value
        m = Range("D4").Value
        d = Range("D5").Value
        xb = Range("D6").Value
        bh = Range("D7").Value
        bd = Range("D8").Value
        bm = Range("D9").Value

 'CALCULATIONS
        'Calculating the Horizontal force on the anchor
        Call Thoriz(T, w, d, Th)

        'Calculating the angle of catenary at the connection
        Pi = 3.1415926536 'Defining the value of Pi
        phi = phi * 180 / (Pi) 'Conversion of rad to deg
        Call Angle(Th, T, phi, X1)

        'Calculating the total line length
        Call Tvert(T, phi, s, w, Tv)

        'Calculating the spread length
        Call spreadlength1(a, s, d, h, X2)
        Call spreadlength(B, xb, h)

        'OUTPUTTING OF VALUES
        Range("D13").Value = Th
        Range("D14").Value = phi
        Range("D15").Value = L
        Range("D16").Value = B
        Range("D17").Value = bdr

End Sub
```

Comment: All your variables except `X2` are defined as `Variant`. If you want to define all of them as double, you have to enter `Dim T as Double, m  as Double, d  as Double...`

Comment: It also helps to indicate on which line the error occurs. You can insert data as formatted tables using tools like [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so that people can copy paste for testing. Images  - we can't really copy paste from.

Comment: Don't declare all of your variables publicly you can easily run into issues doing this if you aren't careful. Declare each of your variables inside their relevant subs. Also, a lot of your Subs probably should be written as Functions

Comment: I have defined the variables as Double as you suggested @FunThomas however VBA still prompts me with the overflow error. Re. the table I can't add it in a comment as I will exceed the character limit (I will keep this in mind for future enquiries, thanks!)

Comment: What is w? You haven't declared it anywhere you may be getting the issue as you're dividing by 0

Comment: @Tom You are right! I did not define a value for w - this solved the overflow problem. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Also your conversion of radians to degrees isn't doing anything either as you're converting it before you give phi any value so you're also multiplying by 0. I think you've got quite a few issues here. I'd also recommend re-writing them as functions. This way you could call them from the worksheet and get rid of your `Calculations` `Sub`